# Slow boot: "Dependency failed for /mnt/usb-NAND_USB2DISK-0:0" and "A start job is running for /dev/disk/by-id/usb-NAND_USB2DISK-0:0"

Tags: boot, usb, mount, fstab, boot-repair

my computer has been booting really slow lately. when i check the boot logs while it shows this.

`[DEPEND] Dependency failed for /mnt/usb-NAND_USB2DISK-0:0.`

`[DEPEND] Dependency failed for Local File Systems.`

`sudo more /etc/fstab` output:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=15563119-c1ff-4f79-b800-4ec135f8175b /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=2E20-626A  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/disk/by-id/usb-NAND_USB2DISK-0:0 /mnt/usb-NAND_USB2DISK-0:0  nosuid,nodev,nofail,noauto,x-gvfs-show 0 0
```

NOTE: i uninstalled KDE before and i think it started to boot slower since then.

i would appreciate help since i really really dont find an answer anywhere and i dont know what to do

Comment: Is the USB storage device connected to your computer during boot? If not, the system is going to look for it as a result of the `fstab` configuration 

Answer (score 0):

Well guys I just commented the line mentioning the usb mount thing in `/etc/fstab` and that fixed the problem. I don't know what that was doing there.

Comment: I’m pretty sure you were trying to make that mount automatically on boot